# updating ImageField with new image using python function

Tags: python, django

I have been trying to create an image editor app using django
since on screen controls are not possible in django templates I have started using function in views.py to do the same but I'm stuck at updating ImageField database with new image

my views.py file is

```
def padding(request, meme_id):
meme = Meme.objects.filter(id = meme_id)
    if not meme:
        return HttpResponse("404 meme not found")
    else:
        old_im = meme.photo
        old_size = old_im.size
        new_size = (old_size[0],old_size[1]+300)
        new_im = Image.new("RGB", new_size)
        new_im.paste(old_im,((new_size[0]-old_size[0])/2,new_size[1]-   old_size[1])/2)
# here i have to update meme.photo with new new_im
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the meme model has an ImageField named image, you'll do the following:

```
new_im = Image.new("RGB", new_size)
meme.image = new_im
meme.save()
```